# Travelling soon and lost UK passport. What can I do?

Tags: schengen, passports, uk-citizens, lost-documents

**UPDATE: Praise your choice of deity, I found it!**

**UPDATE AGAIN: Due to a number of people wanting to know where it was found - I sold my car a couple of months ago and had a bag of stuff I'd removed from the car before it was collected, the bag contained my passport among other things (and a pair of sunglasses - handy!) and was living at the bottom of my wardrobe**

---

I am a UK citizen, born and lived in UK all my life. I have a valid UK passport, I believe it expires in about 2 or 3 years. But I can't find it and I go travelling in 4 days from now.

I intend to visit the following countries: Netherlands, Belgium, Germany, Luxembourg, Austria, Italy, France.  I will be travelling by ferry between England and Belgium (and the reciprocal on the return) and all other travel will be by private car.

I am happy to pay whatever the cost is for a replacement passport but I'm not sure how to get it quickly enough.

On https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently it suggests that I can get one urgently but only if mine is expired or due to expire soon and I cannot use that service if mine is simply lost.

In a panic I tried to phone the passport office on 0300 222 0000, which is the number listed on gov.uk, but it seems fully automated and only tells me to go online and do it there, which I have already failed to do.

Some Googling found this page https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm which strongly suggests that I'll actually be fine without a passport, but I have contacted the support centre for the ferry company and they confirmed I will absolutely need a passport to travel with them.

The only other photographic ID I have is a full UK photocard driving license, which the above page explicitly excludes as a valid form of identification.

Will I be okay travelling through these countries between 23rd June and 10th July with no passport present? If not, how can I expedite the passport application process? It seems impossible to actually speak to anyone at the passport office.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79264/discussion-on-question-by-confused-travelling-soon-and-lost-uk-passport-what-ca).

Answer (score 33):

According to EU rules you need either a passport or a national ID card to travel between EU countries.

However, the UK does not issue national ID cards- there was a whole political issue about possibly introducing them during the Blair government which led to them eventually being rejected.

As a British citizen you absolutely 100% need a passport to leave the UK (except for Ireland...though to get on a plane you still need a passport).

There certainly is a 1-day service for passports. I once used this to **renew** a passport that was soon to run out (only to have said passport stolen a few months later...) and it worked as advertised:

https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently

> ### 1 week Fast Track
>
> Your new passport is delivered to your home within 1 week of your appointment. Someone might need to be in to sign for it.
>
> You can use this service to:
>
> - replace a lost, stolen or damaged passport

(none of the other options apply for *replacing a lost passport*)

The only possible way you would probably be OK without a passport (albeit putting yourself at great risk if you are subject to a random search) is if you're already in continental Europe and travel by land.

From the UK your chances are nil unless you've access to a private boat or some other underhand means.

Comment: Can you confirm if your use of the 1 day passport service was for a regular renewal (yours had expired or was close to expiry) or if it was to replace a lost/stolen passport?

Comment: edited. Yep. Was just to renew- was living in Japan at the time and did it whilst I was visiting home.

Comment: Quote from the online fast track application page "To use Online Premium you’ll need your old passport."

Comment: Ack, sorry then, I think I did have my old one. Though it was in person rather than online that I did it.
Can only recommend calling the passport centre

Comment: Just to confirm, I have been in exactly the same situation as the OP, and the 1-day passport service does *not* work for lost passports. This is explicitly stated on their website, but I also called and spoke to them. I ended up cancelling my flight.

Comment: What about [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) Art 5(4): "Where a Union citizen...does not have the necessary travel documents..., the Member State concerned shall, before turning them back, give such persons every reasonable opportunity to obtain the necessary documents or have them brought to them within a reasonable period of time *or to corroborate or prove by other means that they are covered by the right of free movement and residence"* (emphasis added).  Has nobody tried that?

Comment: @poog It takes weeks to get a passport (the OP quotes a minimum of 7 days); not really a "reasonable period of time" (they're probably thinking hours or a day or so, although I could be wrong).  Sounds like they mean "have someone bring the passport here" not "start the application process and wait".

Comment: @DrEval i think he was asking about the emphasized part, although I don't know what "other means" could be acceptable.

Comment: just a minor nitpick - you can fly to Ireland with just Photo ID such as your DL. I had to do this once while the US Embassy had my passport and it was fine. My father used his OAP bus pass for a while when he lost his passport.

Comment: a week for an emergency replacement? Sheesh. Here in the Netherlands a regular application takes at most a week. Emergency documents can sometimes be handed out in under an hour (though those have limited validity, only for the duration of the trip they're needed for).

Comment: @Ian; hadn't heard this! When was it? A particular airline? Needs looking into more as I'm sure I'd heard some airlines at least insist passport only

Comment: Aer Lingus has a list on their website: https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/passports-and-visas/travel-to-from-britain/

It's a bit weird - as you can only avail of not-travelling with a passport, if you are a citizen AND born in the country - which you can't really confirm without a passport.

Also note, apparently a work ID with a photo is a valid form of ID.

Answer (score 26):

The passport office has an option to receive a callback. I left my name and number and an adviser called me back a couple of hours later.

The adviser explained that the quickest it is possible to replace a lost or stolen passport is 7 days.

The 1 day service is only available for replacements of expired or nearly expired passports that are still in your possession.

I guess I'll need to look harder...

Comment: If the journey is one that you cannot cancel, then I would suggest applying for the passport immediately. The timescale they give is a "within" timescale and there is a *small* chance you could receive it in time to catch your ferry. When I was in this situation I had a cancellable flight and didn't want to take the chance of seeing what would happen (because the cost of cancelling was higher if I waited). But it's worth trying if you have nothing to lose, especially as you will need a new passport anyway. EDIT: The 1 week service costs more than the 3 week, so you do risk something.

Comment: The passport has been found. What a massive relief

Comment: Was it a good hiding place?

Comment: @JBentley when you formally start the lost passport process does it automatically invalidate the lost passport? if so then it may not be such a good idea to start it until you are extremely sure the passport cannot be found.

Comment: @PeterGreen that was exactly my concern, I suspect it would indeed invalidate it, but cannot confirm that with any certainty as luckily I didn't get that far

Comment: @Confused To confirm, when a Lost or Stolen (LS) request is made and the passport is found soon after - it *is* possible to have the request reversed, but there are a number of gotchas in the process; including some situations where the LS is carried out anyway and the recovered passport must be sent to them to be replaced (such as if any 3rd party touched your passport, or you called the police). In the best case, you still can't travel untill the LS is reversed and confirmed to you in writing - which would likely make you miss the flight anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Find your passport!

Looking for a passport is quite a stressful time, which implies doing mistakes, forgetting where you put it, when the answer can be easy.

Think out of the box! For the anecdote, I once “lost” my passport before going on a cycle trip. Therefore we could not use the ferry to reach our destination in Greece. When I got home after the trip, I unpacked and found my passport in... a small pocket in my bag! Check your old bags and pockets!

When did you have it for the last time? Where? What is your favorite safe place? Maybe you’ve hidden too well, but in a place you know well. Be smart and methodical in your research, it’s probably not in the kitchen.

Good luck!

Edit: just saw you found it! Glad

Answer (score 4):

There are only two permanent border checkpoints on your route: the departure and destination ports of the ferry. From my experience traveling to the UK, **all** traffic is checked on the France->UK routes. Outbound traffic from the UK is scrutinized less thoroughly, but the chance of having to show your passport is still too high to risk traveling without one.

Comment: It clearly states on the ferry company (P&O) website that a passport is required for admission

Comment: True. In practice though they rarely ask for it, because you don't get to their offices  until you've passed customs.

Comment: @Hobbes this is a ferry to Belgium.  There's no passport control on the UK side, is there?

Comment: @Hobbes I have travelled through Eurotunnel many times and being asked for a passport on the outgoing leg seems hit and miss. The return journey is a very different story

Comment: @phoog, I don't know, I haven't used those. But both Dover and Harwich have passport control outbound.

Comment: Is that new?  I sailed from Harwich once, years ago, and don't remember there being an outbound passport check.

Comment: @phoog The UK began doing passport checks on exit in 2015. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-32205970

Comment: Before the exit checks your passport could (and often was) be checked by the ferry company as they needed to be sure you could enter France (or whichever country.)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider having a go with [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) Article 5(4):

> Article 5
>
> Right of entry
>
> 1. Without prejudice to the provisions on travel documents applicable to national border controls, **Member States shall grant Union citizens leave to enter their territory with a valid identity card or passport** and shall grant family members who are not nationals of a Member State leave to enter their territory with a valid passport.
>
> ...
>
> 4. **Where a Union citizen**, or a family member who is not a national of a Member State, **does not have the necessary travel documents** or, if required, the necessary visas, **the Member State concerned shall, before turning them back, give such persons every reasonable opportunity to** obtain the necessary documents or have them brought to them within a reasonable period of time or to ***corroborate or prove by other means that they are covered by the right of free movement and residence.***

(emphasis added)

I wouldn't think it likely to succeed, but you might just get away with it if you have enough proof "by other means."  If you're willing to risk being turned back at the ferry and you're unable to find your passport, it might be worth a shot.  Please come back and let us know what happens if you try it.

(Based on [Hobbes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/44304/hobbes)'s [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117097/travelling-soon-and-lost-passport-what-can-i-do/117114?noredirect=1#comment285780_117111) on [his answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/117111/19400), it seems that it is more likely for this to work on a ferry to France with juxtaposed immigration controls, so you might consider changing your itinerary.)

Comment: "If you're willing to risk being turned back at the ferry" you wrote, but the line above is not about being turned back at the ferry, but having already reached another country.

Comment: @DrEval which line is about having already reached the other country?  The line I quoted?  If so, that is not correct; article 5 concerns the "right of entry."

Comment: "Where a Union citizen, or a family member who is not a national of a Member State.... the Member State concerned shall, before turning them back"

Comment: @DrEval see my edit.  That line explicitly concerns the right of entry and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, I was only addressing the line you quoted in your answer. The new text in the edit explains what can happen at the destination. There's nothing there about leaving your country first, which is where the problem is.

Comment: @DrEval I see your point. Article 4 concerns the right of exit; it allows countries to require those leaving to hold a valid passport or ID. But the UK does not check passports on exit, so the problem will be the ferry company. I had been thinking, because of a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117097/travelling-soon-and-lost-passport-what-can-i-do/117114?noredirect=1#comment285780_117111) on another answer, that this would be possible because of juxtaposed controls, but for a ferry to Belgium, I suppose there are no juxtaposed controls.

Comment: @Belle-Sophie Juxtaposed controls for ferries are covered by an agreement between France and the UK only (Treaty of Le Touquet); no other Schengen country participates. 
 Juxtaposed controls exist in Dover, Calais, and Dunkirk, so it is in fact different for Belgium and Hull.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juxtaposed_controls#Ferry

Comment: @phoog Ah, that's what that is! I didn't know what the word meant.